# Bootstrap scaffolding and semantic HTML

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I looked at other questions regarding Twitter Bootstrap and semantic HTML5-tags but couldn't find a satisfying answer.

Twitter Bootstrap allows you to do many advanced layouts of web pages thanks to a rather large amount of scaffolding. There are divs in divs in divs in divs before you get to the actual text content of the page.

I am fully aware that you **can** switch div to more or less whatever semantic tag you need, **but which is the best practice?** Personally, I place the semantic tags as **close** to the content as possible. The below examples show a panel in a column (the row is omitted). All three examples work. The first example is pretty much taken from the bootstrap manual. The second example is how I write the code. But the third example works fine as well.

Which way would you do it? And why? (And my question concerns not only panels in columns per se, but the whole shabang: forms, jumbotrons, modals, popups, alerts and so on.)

```
<div class="col-md-9">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">Headertext</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <p>...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-9">
  <section class="panel panel-default">
    <header class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">Headertext</h3>
    </header>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <p>...</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>

<section class="col-md-9">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <header class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">Headertext</h3>
    </header>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <p>...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Your question is too opinionated. Both work exactly the same, it is just a matter of preference...

Comment: The second and third one are basically the same. I'd personally prefer the second one as it enables you to place multiple sections in a column. `<div>`'s don't affect the document outline at all, so it really doesn't matter how many you nest.